# Issues sending mailers to a group - not sending but report shows sent to 90 people

Tags: civimail

Is anyone else spending more time fixing things in CiviCrm than actually using it?

Im on the latest version 5.49.1 and latest Drupal 9 version. Installed ckeditor5 (using embedded images as could not get paths to work).

Every time I go to do a mailer its so painful - what should take me 10 minutes takes over an hour.

Constant messages about not being able to save - have to come out, change template, turn ckeditor on off and on...

Save a draft and go back in and nothing has been saved - start again.

Schedule a mailer and then trigger the scheduled job (issue with cron)

Mailer report says 90 emails delivered yet Im getting nothing - not even a test send. Drupal 9 recent log messages are so garbled its not easy to debug (D7 was a dream compared to 9).

I also have issues with Stripe webhooks failing all the time and so many issues in the logs that I dont know where to start. TBH I spend so much time firefighting I think I need to look for another membership solution (sorry - rant over).

Comment: hard to know where to start answering. we manage dozens of sites using CiviMail without the users complaining about using the mailer not saving changes etc etc

Comment: Are you using ckeditor5, same civicrm version as me and sendmail? Mine was working with issues but now wont send.

Comment: the couple of sites i checked are using ckeditor4 and we generally send using mail()